# Netstjs - multiple global guards with user access

Tags: nestjs

I want to use the guard which will check the database if current user is active on each request. From the research I have done, I can use `request.user` only if the the guard is not global.
Options I have are:

1. Register guards on each controller/resolver (downside: duplicate code)
2. Extract and decode `jwt` from `request.headers` (jwt is then decoded twice: once from me and once under the hood (I am using `AuthGuard('jwt')`))

What is the best (and cleanest) solution for doing the needed filtering? Is there any better option available?

```
@Injectable()
export class IsUserActiveGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(
    private userService: UsersService) { }

async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const request = ctx.getContext().req;
    const user = request.user;
    if (user) 
        return await this.userService.checkActiveUser(user.id);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Move the checkActiveUser method to a new service, maybe some called **GuardService** and create a global module with **GuardService** as a provider, then import that global module to the root module (often called AppModule) and that's it. You can use your Guard on your application without importing the Module again.

Inside the guard you can have this code to get the token and payload

```
const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
if (token == null) throw new UnauthorizedException('Null Access Token');

try {
 verify(
    token,
    `${this.config.get<string>('JWT_ACCESS_KEY')}`,
  ) as IAccess;
  req.session = user; //User Session
  /* Some extra validation here */
} catch (error) {
  throw new ForbiddenException('Invalid Access Token');
}
return true;
```

Comment: But how can I get the current user info inside a function? Is the function `checkActiveUser` getting triggered on every request?

Comment: Just add the guard to the controller using the decorator @UseGuards(YourCustomGuard) in the controller class or on each route, and of course, be sure that you're sending the token on the header auth, then you can extract the payload of the token using the function that I added to the anwser.

Comment: That is the solution I am using currently, but as I asked in a question, is there any better solution? Said solution required adding guard on each controller class.

Comment: Yes, there's a better solution, use a middleware instead of a guard, and apply that middleware on your AppModule file